# why i'm seeing webpack module 7 is not a function?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, webpack

I'm using react js and i'm trying to use webticker lib [webticker](https://maze.digital/webticker/)

and this is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#webticker').webTicker()
});


class App extends Component {
..... // the rest of the component then in render 

<ul id="webTicker">
    <li>This List Item will scroll infintely</li>
    <li>And this one will follow it</li>
    <li>Finally when it goes out of screen, it will queue again at the end</li>
</ul>
```

but i get this error

`TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7___default(...)(...).webTicker is not a function`

i've tried loading it in `componentDidMount` and also tried `document.ready` but this also gave me the same error.

Comment: It means that the library isn't correctly included in the web page. Using jQuery with React is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Using JQuery with React can be problematic for reasons like this. An easier solution would be to find a react-compatible library that has the same functionality you need.

Comment: You could possibly put the JQuery code in a separate script file and load it after React.

Comment: @KenoClayton unfortunately  this lib is only support jquery and i couldn't find any alternative , but can you explain more about how to **put the JQuery code in a separate script file and load it after React**

Comment: and if i tried to write from scratch with custom css i made ,it lags for a second and this is some kind annoying , @KenoClayton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's never a good idea to use JQuery and React together, so this solution will try to let them operate separately.

Considering that React will attach itself to a particular div in the DOM, we can place our web ticker as a sibling to it.

E.g.

```html
<!-- React attaches to this -->
<div id="root"></div>

<!-- Web Ticker attaches to this -->
<ul id="webTicker" style="display:none">
    <li>This List Item will scroll infintely</li>
    <li>And this one will follow it</li>
    <li>Finally when it goes out of screen, it will queue again at the end</li>
</ul>

<!-- Don't forget to load scripts -->
<script src="./path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./path/to/jquery.webticker.min.js"></script>
<script src="./path/to/your/scripts.js></script>
```

Now you'd only want to show that list if React has loaded, so you could do something like

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#root').children().length > 0) {
        $('#webticker')
          .show()
          .webTicker()
    }
});
```